# How to set up Android reminder app alarm?

Tags: java

How set up alarm manager?  I need to set up alarm for every hour. For example 2 pm 4 pm or 14 or 16. Please let me know if someone knows about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, so I don't know what you have tried or where you've gotten to in your efforts. I'd be much more confident on what to answer if add some context in the future :-)

Starting off with alarms I would recommend that you read this page: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms on how to schedule alarms. Check out the section "Choose an alarm type" as this may be what you're looking for.